# Difference between Working Voltage and Isolation Voltage?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, isolation, insulation

I am building a board to collect data from a 2000V system.

The board is going to be powered from a USB port on a laptop and data collected directly into the laptop.

I am looking at  Isolated 5Vto5V DCDC converters and confused between Isolation Voltage and Working Voltage.

Look at this datasheet:
https://www.tracopower.com/sites/default/files/products/datasheets/thb3_datasheet.pdf
The Isolation is 4800V but 'working voltage' is only 1000V

Other DCDCs from that range are even worse, e.g. 300V 'working voltage' with 3kV isolation

Does this mean the DCDC will be dangerous to use to isolate the 5V USB from the 1700V system?

FYI the data will be collected using a digital isolator with also a 3kV isolation but again, the 'working voltage' appears much lower

Comment: The isolation voltage is just the rated maximum between two galvanic systems that are supposed to remain isolated. Just think of it as insulation, like what surrounds an insulated wire. That doesn't mean a circuit works right at that voltage. It just means the insulation is guaranteed to not break down below the rating. The circuit itself will have a different number, its working voltage, which is the worst-case stand-off rating for a working circuit. You haven't said much about the application details, but you may need a working voltage well above 2k.

Comment: PD will be your main limiting factor. Don’t overlook it! _”Does this mean the DCDC will be dangerous to use to isolate the 5V USB from the 1700V system?”_ For continuous use, yes!

Comment: It is a normal practice then he maximum voltage 4 times bigger the working voltage. Isolator should be chosen by continuous working voltage.

Comment: would a radio link work? ... you could connect the circuit between 995 V and 1000 V to get the required 5 V power supply

Comment: @jsotola Or fiberoptic

Comment: @DKNguyen that also crossed my mind ... should have voiced it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The Insulation Voltage Rating only needs to operate for a limited time such as 1 minute as the long term stress may reduce MTBF with this or other reasons as below.
- SMPS supplies with Y caps are tested with HVDC as the Y caps would conduct too much power with sustained kVac and are intended for lightning noise ingress or SMPS harmonic egress.  The voltage is usally ramped up slowly in 1 second to limit current which looks like leakage current but are actually Y caps charging up to PE gnd.
- Generally the 30 or 60 second Isolation kV rms test may be tested with peak voltage DC and/or tested with 10% higher voltage for 1 second instead.  All products must be 100% tested for isolation that use Protective Earth, PE with AC.
- Working voltage is self explanatory